# CSS: Can't make space for sidebar

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet, multiple-columns

I'm trying to have my ads show up on the the right side of a page. I have set the width of the content & navigation to 75%.

```
div.comments, div.navigation {
    margin-left:1.5em;
    margin-right:1.5em;
    width: 75%;
}
#content {
margin: 1em 0px;
width: 75%;
float: left;
padding-top: 1.1em;
}
```

the side bar is set to 200px. Which is much less than 25% on most screen.
But the content still is taking up some extra space display here in the orange.
[image]

I cannot figure where this is coming from. I've spent the last hour using google developer tool to resolve it. Below is style.css. The page can be found at [gazzetesm.com](http://gazettesm.com/2012/10/relief-workers-bound-for-st-john-the-baptist-parish/). The [Our Partner's Page](http://gazettesm.com/our-partners/) style is what I am trying to achieve.

style.css

```
/*  
Theme Name: Gonzo Daily
Theme URI: http://greatgonzo.net/projects/gonzodaily
Description: Gonzo Daily is flexible-width three-column theme for WordPress. It has a newspaper-like front page, featuring three columns of text for browsers that support CSS columns (currently only Firefox, more to come)<br /><br />Wordpress Widgets ready.<br /><br />The font used in the header is <a href="http://openfontlibrary.org/media/files/gluk/306">Gputeks</a> by<a href="http://openfontlibrary.org/media/people/gluk"> gluk</a>, licensed under <a href="http://scripts.sil.org/OFL">SIL Open Font License</a>.
Version: 1.4
Author: Milen Petrinski - Gonzo
Author URI: http://greatgonzo.net/
Tags: black, two-columns, three-columns, right-sidebar, flexible-width
*/

/**
* Eric Meyer's Reset stylesheet - http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/
*/

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,
a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,
del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,
small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,
dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,
fieldset,form,label,legend,
table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    font-size:100%;
    font-family:inherit;
    vertical-align:baseline;
}

/*
 * Created by gluk with FontForge 1.0 (http://fontforge.sf.net) 
 * This Font Software is licensed under the SIL Open Font License, V.1.1. 
 * This license is available with a FAQ at: http://scripts.sil.org/OFL.
 * Copyright (c) 2008, gluk,(gluksza@wp.pl) with Reserved Font Name Gputeks.
 */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Gputeks";
    src:url(fonts/Gputeks-Regular.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}

/*
 * Created by gluk with FontForge 1.0 (http://fontforge.sf.net) 
 * This Font Software is licensed under the SIL Open Font License, V.1.1. 
 * This license is available with a FAQ at: http://scripts.sil.org/OFL.
 * Copyright (c) 2008, gluk,(gluksza@wp.pl) with Reserved Font Name Gputeks.
 */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Gputeks";
    src:url(fonts/Gputeks-Bold.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
}


/**
* GLOBALS
*/

html {
    background: #fff;
    text-align:center;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    text-align:justify;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    max-width:95%;
    line-height:1;
    color:black;
    font-family:Georgia,"Lucida bright","Times new roman",Georgia,"lucida bright",serif;
    font-size:11pt;
}

h1, h2 {
    font-size:1.8em;
    text-align:left;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, Palladio, "URW Palladio L", "Book Antiqua", Baskerville, "Bookman Old Style", "Bitstream Charter", "Nimbus Roman No9 L", Garamond, "Apple Garamond", "ITC Garamond Narrow", "New Century Schoolbook", "Century Schoolbook", "Century Schoolbook L", Georgia, serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}

h3 {
    text-align:left;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:1.1em;
    font-style:italic;
    margin-bottom: 1.4em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height:1.5em;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}

hr {
    display:none;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#633B18;
    font-weight:inherit;
    font-style:inherit;
}

a:visited {
    color:#633B18;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#AE3000;
    /*text-shadow: #666 2px 2px 5px;*/
}

a:focus {
    color:#AE3000;
    /*outline-width:.1em;*/
}

p {
    line-height:1.5em;
    margin-bottom:1.5em;
}

li {
    line-height:1.5em;
}

ul, ol {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    list-style:none;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

caption, th, td {
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:normal;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content:"";
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:"" "";
}

blockquote {
    margin:0;
    padding:1.15em .5em 1.25em 1.5em;
    color:#999;
    font-family:Georgia,"Lucida bright","Times new roman",serif;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-style:italic;
    line-height: 1.25em;
}

blockquote * {
    line-height: 1.25em;
    margin-bottom:0;
}

abbr {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #633B18;
}


img {
    border:none;
}

strong {
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style: inherit;
}

em {
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:inherit;
}

.alignleft {
    float:left;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}

img.alignleft {
    float:left;
    margin-right:1em;
}

img.alignright {
    float:right;
    margin-left:1em;
}

img.alignright {
    float:right;
    margin-left:1em;
}

.aligncenter {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
a img.alignright {float:right; margin:0 0 1em 1em}
a img.alignleft {float:left; margin:0 1em 1em 0}
a img.aligncenter {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto}

code {
    font-family:courier,"courier new", monospace;
}

pre {
    display:block;
    font-family:courier,"courier new", monospace;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:1.5em;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    padding:1.5em 1.5em;
    margin-top:0em;
    margin-bottom:1.5em;
    overflow:auto;
}


/**
* HEADER
*/

#header {
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-align:left;
    border-bottom:2px solid #AE3000;
}

#header h1, #header p.title {
    color:#AE3000;
    font-size:2.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: Gputeks, "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Liberation Sans", Verdana, "Verdana Ref", sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:2;
    /*letter-spacing: 0.1em;*/
    margin:0;
}


#header h1 a, #header p.title a {
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#header div.description {
    color:#999;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    float:right;
    margin-top: -2em;
}


/**
* MAIN NAVIGATION
*/

ul#navigation {
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    margin-top:-2em;
}

ul#navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: Gputeks, "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Liberation Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, "Verdana Ref", sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:.5em;
    line-height:1;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    word-spacing: -.2em;
}

ul#navigation li a {
}

ul#navigation li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}

/**
 * First post on index page
 */

div.latest {
    padding: 2em 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    border-bottom:2px solid #AE3000;
}

div.latest h2 {
    font-size: 5em;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 1em;
}

div.latest h2 a:link,
div.latest h2 a:visited,
div.latest h2 a:active {
    color:inherit;
}

div.latest p.details_small {
    margin:0;
}

div.latest div.post_content {
    margin-top:1.5em;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 1%;
}

div.post_content > p:first-child:first-line {
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight:bold;
}

div.post_content > p:first-child:first-letter {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    font-size:2.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    padding-top: .2em;
    margin-right: .2em;
}

div.latest img {
    padding:2px;
    background:#AE3000;
    border:10px solid #ccc;
    max-width:90%;
    height: auto;
}



/**
* FIRST MAIN COLUMN
*/

#content {
    margin: 1em 0px;
    width:79%;
    float:left;
    padding-top:1.1em;
}

#content.home {
    padding-top:0em;
    background: none;
    border:none;
}

#content.single, #content.archive {
    padding-top:0em;
}

#content div.post {
    margin: 0 0em 0em .5em;
    padding: 0em 1em 1em 1em;
    color:#000;
}

#content div.list {
    margin: 0 0em 1.6em .5em;
    padding: 0em 1em 0em 1em;
    color:#000;
    border:none;
    background:none;
}

#content div.post div.more {
    padding-top:.2em
}

#content h1 {
    color: #000;
    font-size:3em;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0em 0em .5em .5em;
}

#content div.post h1 {
    font-size:3em;
    margin: 0em 0em .5em 0em;
}

#content div.list h2 {
    font-size:1.4em;
    line-height:1.1em;
    padding-top:.1em;
    margin-bottom:.3em;
}

#content div.post h2 {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}

#content div.post h3 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#content div.post h2,
#content div.post h3,
#content div.post h4
{
    color: #000;
}

#content div.post h2 a:visited,
#content div.post h3 a:visited,
#content div.post h4 a:visited
{
    color:#633B18;
}

#content div.post h2 a:hover,
#content div.post h3 a:hover,
#content div.post h4 a:hover
{
    color:#AE3000;
}

#content p.tag-cloud {
    margin-top:3em;
}    

#content p.tag-cloud a {
    color: #000;
}    

#content ul, div.latest ul {
    list-style-type:square;
    padding-left:3em;
}

#content ol, div.latest ol {
    list-style-type:decimal;
    padding-left:3em;
}

#content img {
    padding:2px;
    background:#AE3000;
    border:10px solid #ccc;
    max-width:90%;
    margin:10px;
}

#content img.noborder {
    border:0px;
    padding:0;
    background: none;
}

.navigation div {
    line-height:1.5em;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}

.navigation .prev {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
}

.navigation .next {
    float:right;
    width:40%;
    text-align:right;
}

.details_small {
    font-size:1em;
    color:#999;
    margin:0;
}

div.list .details_small {
    margin-top:-0.2em;
}

div.list p {
    margin-bottom:0;
}

.details_small a {
    color:#999;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

p.date {
    text-align:right;
    font-size:1em;
    color:#999;
}

span.gravatar {
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

span.gravatar img {
    border: 5px solid #999;
}

div.column {
    float:left;
}

div.left {
    padding-right:0;
    width:40%;
}

div.right {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    width:48%;
}


/**
* COMMENTS
*/

div.comments, div.navigation {
    margin-left:1.5em;
    margin-right:1.5em;
    width: 75%;
}

h2#comments{
    margin-top:.2em;
    margin-bottom:1.5em;
    padding-bottom:0em;
    font-weight:normal !important;
}

ol.commentlist {
    list-style-type: none !important;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left:0px !important;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding-bottom:.1em;
}

.commentlist li {
    margin-bottom:1.5em;
    padding-bottom:.5em;
    padding-top:.8em;
    border-top:1px solid #999;
}

.commentlist li.author {
    border-top:1px solid #AE3000;
}

.commentlist li p {
    margin-bottom:0em;
}

.commentlist li p.comment-data {
    margin-bottom:1.5em;
}

.commentlist li p.comment-author {
    font-size:1.5em;
    line-height:1em;
    font-family:Georgia,"Lucida bright","Times new roman",serif;
    font-style:italic;
    /*font-weight:bold;*/
    /*font-variant:small-caps;*/
    margin-bottom:0em;
}

.commentlist ul li,
.commentlist ol li {
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
    border-bottom:0;
}

.commentlist ul {
    padding-left:1.5em;
    list-style-type:square;
}

.commentlist ol {
    padding-left:1.5em;
    /*list-style-type:lower-alpha;*/
}

p.nocomments {
    padding-bottom:.5em;
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.5em;
    line-height:1em;
}

.allowed-tags {
    display:none;
}

.commentlist li span.comment_number {
    display:none;
    float:right;
    font-size:40px;
    color: #999;
    margin-top:.3em;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.commentlist li span.avatar {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    margin:-2px 0px 0 0;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    text-align:right;
}

#content .commentlist li span.avatar img.avatar {
    display:block;
    width:48px;
    height:48px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #999 !important;
    background: #eee;
}

#content .commentlist li.author span.avatar img.avatar {
    border: 1px solid #AE3000 !important;
}

h2#respond {
    margin-bottom:1.5em;
}

/**
* FORMS
*/

#commentform {
    margin-bottom:1.5em;
    padding-bottom:0em;
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
}

textarea {
    width:99%;
}

/**
* RIGHT SIDEBARS
*/

.sidebar {
    padding:0px;
    float:right;
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}

#sidebarFrame {
    float:right;
    padding:1em 0px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.sidebar{
    width: 98%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar h2 {
    font-size:1.3em;
    line-height:1.2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom:.2em;
}

.sidebar ul {
    margin-right:1.5em;
}

.sidebar ul li {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom:0.4em;
    padding-bottom:.5em;
}

.sidebar h2 {
    margin:.2em 0 -.2em 0;
    border: none;
    padding-bottom:.2em;
}

.sidebar ul {
    margin:0 1.5em .2em 0;
    padding:0 0 .5em 0;
}

.sidebar ul li {
    border:1px solid #999999;
    padding:1em 10px .5em 10px;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    line-height:1.5em !important;
}

.sidebar ul li:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.sidebar ul li ul,
.sidebar ul li ul li {
    border: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.sidebar img {
    float:left;
    margin:.3em .5em 0 0;
}

.sidebar .vcard img.photo {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #eee;
}

.sidebar ul,
.sidebar ul li ul li,
.sidebar ul li ul li ul {
    border-bottom:0;
    margin:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}

.sidebar ul li ul {
    font-size:.9em;
}

.sidebar ul li ul li,
.sidebar ul li ul li {
    border-bottom:1px dotted #999;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    padding:.1em 0;
}

.sidebar ul li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}

.sidebar ul li ul li ul {
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding-left:10px;
    border-left:1px solid #aaa;
}

.sidebar a {
    /*color: #999;*/
}

.sidebar a:hover {
    /*color: #99000e;*/
}

/**
* FOOTER
*/

#footer {
    padding:10px;
    border-top:2px solid #AE3000;
    clear:both;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:.9em;
}

#footer p {
    margin-left:67%;
    padding-left:.5em;
    padding-top:1.5em;
}

#footer p:first-child {
    float:left;
    width:65%;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding-left:1em;
    padding-right:0;
    padding-top:1.5em;
}

ins.adsbygoogle
{ 
    display:block !important;
    margin
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #content says it's width is set @ 79%.

Instead of floating three containers to the left (which is causing this issue) I would put them all in another container and float it to the left:

```
<div class="floatme">
   <div id="#container">..</div>
   <div class="..">..</div>
   <div class="..">..</div>
</div>
```

or remove the float from the top 3 and just float the comment to the right.

Comment: After looking at some other post it really seems to be specific to this post. http://gazettesm.com/2013/01/bipolar-survivor/ looks just fine. And the width at 79% doesn't seem to matter. I can set it to 2% and the sidebar will still be at the bottm.

Comment: of course - I'm not pointing out that the 79% is the problem. I was just saying that there was a inconsistency in the code. The problem in the structure is that you have 3 left-floated element on top of the comment element that you would like to float to the right. Also setting margin will add to the width unless you specify box-model CSS. hope that makes sense.

Comment: again - wrap the #content, .comment, .navigation in a div and float it to the left with 75%, no margin/padding. Then, float the sidebar to the right with no-margin, display:inline-block

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your HTML around a little.  In particular, move the div with id "sidebarFrame" immediately after the div with id "content".  When I did this in FireBug, the layout shows up as you describe it.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do that. I'm not much of a word press person. The sidebar is actually a widget. And I don't see it in any of the .php files

Comment: My WordPress is rusty, but I think there's an editor that lets you work on you page content, including where widgets are located.  Does it look like what you want in the jsfiddle?

Comment: yes your fiddle is great, if you look at any other post on the site they appear the same, Its just this post.

Answer (score 1):

Your columns are not aligning because your .comments and .navigation elements are block level elements, which will not allow the .sidebarFrame to fill in the empty space. try putting those two elements inside of the left floated #content section, or wrap #content, .comments and .navigation in a left floated element.

Comment: I've tried that but no luck. I seem's to be a problem with the post it self, I'm going to look at to code for the post and see if I can find something.